# Проблема восстановления строки по предмету биоинформатика

Tags: python, python-3.x

ЗАДАЧА КОДА: Решите задачу восстановления строки.
Ввод: Целое число k, за которым следует список k-мерных шаблонов.
Вывод: Текст строки с k-мерным составом, равным шаблонам. (Если существует несколько ответов, вы можете
вернуть любой.)

Пример ввода:
4
CTTA
асса
TACC
GGCT
GCTT
TTAC

Образец выходных данных:
GGCTTACCA

Напишите программу. Тестируется через stdin → stdout

Я сам написал код на Python, и при вводе данных в консоль, выдается правильный ответ, но когда вставляешь код на сайт, выводит ошибку Wrong Answer. Помогите исправить или сделать заново. Вот код который я делал сам.

```
    def extend_string(current, remaining):
        if not remaining:
            return current
        suffix = current[-k + 1:]
        for i, kmer in enumerate(remaining):
            if kmer.startswith(suffix):
                new_remaining = remaining[:i] + remaining[i+1:]
                result = extend_string(current + kmer[-1], new_remaining)
                if result:
                    return result
        return ""

    for i, kmer in enumerate(kmers):
        remaining_kmers = kmers[:i] + kmers[i+1:]
        result = extend_string(kmer, remaining_kmers)
        if result:
            return result

    return ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = int(input())
    kmers = [input().strip() for _ in range(6)]  # Замените 6 на необходимое количество ваших k-меров
    result = construct(k, kmers)
    print(result)
```

Comment: `range(6)` ????

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если менять `range(k)` , то код принимает только 4 нуклеотида и  не выводит ответ.

Comment: Научитесь считывать все строки до конца входного потока. Без этого ничего не будет работать.